# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error when running next.js app

Tags: next.js

I am running the next.js app (13.14 version) in the mac and ubuntu environment.
The mac environment is running without the problem, however running the code in the ubuntu gives me the error,

```
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffc7cf99650
 1: 0xb72001  [next-router-worker]
 2: 0x1bfa314 V8_Fatal(char const*, ...) [next-router-worker]
 3: 0xe67b48  [next-router-worker]
 4: 0x1015fc2  [next-router-worker]
 5: 0x1016939  [next-router-worker]
 6: 0x11d6593 v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [next-router-worker]
 7: 0x15d9e59  [next-router-worker]
```

i don't know what goes wrong with this, it might have 2 causes.

1. node incompatibility where node version in mac is 18.16 whereas node version in ubuntu is 16.20.
2. memory issues
   i checked my ubuntu system memory has 6715 mb, it should be enough i guess.

any ideas how to solve the issue